# Bootstrap styles (row and col) between components

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using Angular and Bootstrap and I have this component which outputs correctly:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Hello</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Hello</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, I create a new component  which contains:

```
<div class="col">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>
```

And I put in into my parent component like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <app-my-component></app-my-component>
        <app-my-component></app-my-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Bootstrap styles seems not to work. It is like the `col` style in the app-my-component doesn't know the `row` of the parent component.

How can I get those styles get working properly?

Comment: remove the `div class="row"></div>` from the parent component and put it in the new component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put only the `h2` in the component.
The `col` classes work only if their direct parent is a `row`.

You may try *mast3rd3mon*'s tip:

> remove the `<div class="row"></div>` from the parent component and put it in the new component